# I want to create wordpress users with user role and with send mail to user by cron file for 10 million users

Tags: php, wordpress

What is the right process of create wordpress user by cron file?

I need to create wordpress users using email id that already i have database table for that.
Using cron file i want to create wordpress users, set password to database that already i have, and also send mail to all users after set password into password column.

Because i have millions of business data with email id. And i want to connect all that business with wordpress user.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a `cron_create_user.php` file with below the code

```
require( '/path/to/wp-load.php' );

$password = wp_generate_password( 12, true );

 // get user details from DB

$WP_array = array (
    'user_login'    =>  $username,
    'user_email'    =>  $email,
    'user_pass'     =>  $password,
    'user_url'      =>  $website,
    'first_name'    =>  $first_name,
    'last_name'     =>  $last_name,
    'nickname'      =>  $nickname,
    'description'   =>  $bio,
) ;

$user_id = wp_insert_user( $WP_array ) ;

if ( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
   wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, null, both ); 
}
```

2. set up cron from your host for this file `cron_create_user.php`
3. Add this code `functions.php`

   ```
   add_filter( 'wp_new_user_notification_email' , 'edit_user_notification_email', 10, 3 );

   function edit_user_notification_email( $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname ) {

       $message = sprintf(__( "Welcome to %s! Here's how to log in:" ), $blogname ) . "\r\n";
       $message .= wp_login_url() . "\r\n";
       $message .= sprintf(__( 'Username: %s' ), $user->user_login ) . "\r\n";
       $message .= sprintf(__( 'Password: %s' ), $user->user_pass ) . "\r\n\r\n";
       $message .= sprintf(__( 'If you have any problems, please contact me at %s.'), get_option( 'admin_email' ) ) . "\r\n";
       $message .= __('Adios!');

       $wp_new_user_notification_email['message'] = $message;
       $user_email = stripslashes($user->user_email);
       wp_mail($user_email, sprintf(__('[%s] Your username and password'), get_option('blogname')), $message);

       return $wp_new_user_notification_email;

   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I also thinking that code for create cron.So, my  assumption is right.

Comment: Hello, i added that code in cron file and user was generated fine but email notification not worked. I want to send email notification to user only.Please help me.

Comment: Also i used "wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, null, 'user' ); "   for send email to only users

Comment: require( '/path/to/wp-load.php' );

// get user details from DB

// foreach loop start //

$password = wp_generate_password( 12, true );

$WP_array = array (
    'user_login'    =>  $username,
    'user_email'    =>  $email,
    'user_pass'     =>  $password,
    'user_url'      =>  $website,
    'first_name'    =>  $first_name,
    'last_name'     =>  $last_name,
    'nickname'      =>  $nickname,
    'description'   =>  $bio,
) ;

$user_id = wp_insert_user( $WP_array ) ;

if ( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
   wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, null, 'user' ); 
}

Comment: // foreach loop end //

Comment: Ok. i will check.

Comment: Hello, i added that filter in functions.php but not worked. Email not sent to user. I used "wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, null, user ); " for email send to user

Comment: Are you checking in local?

Comment: Did you check the mail log?

Comment: Email notification worked in wordpress site. But not worked in cron file.

Comment: Did you install SMTP in wordpress site?

Comment: Yes. No any records in mail log

Comment: Yes i used SMTP plugin

Comment: I update my answer with 2 new lines code `$user_email = stripslashes($user->user_email);
            wp_mail($user_email, sprintf(__('[%s] Your username and password'), get_option('blogname')), $message);` try this

Comment: Hello, i used "Easy WP SMTP" plugin. So current  i checked test mail using admin side so it generated authenticate problem. So, i hope your code will work after  solved SMTP problem

Comment: Thank you for help.

Comment: Glad to help you :)